# How to show a recyclerview on fragment from sqlite using cursor and looping

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, database-cursor

I have adding a data on recycler view with cursor on fragment in view pager, but recycler view item not showing. I use looping for getting data from sqlite.

I tried to use for, and while for looping but recyclerview still not showing. I think may be no data exist in sqlite, but after checking it the data is exist.

```
private void prepareNamaNilaiData(String kelas, String mapel) {
    Cursor c = MainActivity.myClass.lihatNamaNilai(kelas, mapel, "Pengetahuan");
    NamaNilai namaNilai[] = new NamaNilai[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.getCount() != 0) {
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            //showMessage("BELUM ADA DATA", "Belum ada nilai pengetahuan "+ c.getString(0) + " pada kelas "+ c.getString(1));
            namaNilai[i] = new NamaNilai(c.getString(0), c.getString(1));
            namaNilaiList.add(namaNilai[i]);
            i++;
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        namaNilaiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return;
    } else {
        showMessage("BELUM ADA DATA", "Belum ada nilai pengetahuan " + mapel + " pada kelas " + kelas);
    }
}
```

And this is code when I call prepareNamaNilaiData method

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvNamaPengetahuan);
    namaNilaiAdapter = new NamaNilaiAdapter(namaNilaiList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(namaNilaiAdapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    try {
        String message1 = getArguments().getString(KEY_KELAS);
        String message2 = getArguments().getString(KEY_MAPEL);
        if ((message1 != null) && (message2 != null)) {
            prepareNamaNilaiData(message1,message2);
        } else {
            prepareNamaNilaiData("-", "-");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is cursor code I called on prepareNamaNilaiData

```
 public Cursor lihatNamaNilai(String kelas, String mapel, String jenis_nilai) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT NAMA_NILAI, TANGGAL FROM " + TABLE_Nilai 
                            + " WHERE KELAS = ? AND MAPEL = ? AND JENIS_NILAI = ? ORDER BY NAMA_NILAI"
                            ,new String[] {kelas, mapel, jenis_nilai});
    return c;
}
```

I expect the loop can show all of data needed from sqlite to recyclerview. But data does not appear in recyclerview

There is no error displayed on logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Log.e(“count===“,namaNilaiList.size())` when the loop finished, and check your adapter,Maybe did not declared LayoutInflater …just maybe.

Comment: Log.e(“count===“,namaNilaiList.size()) is not working, and don't read the database.

Comment: LayoutInflater is declared in my adapter.. Have you another solution?

Comment: I see your code' while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            //showMessage("BELUM ADA DATA", "Belum ada nilai pengetahuan "+ c.getString(0) + " pada kelas "+ c.getString(1));
            namaNilai[i] = new NamaNilai(c.getString(0), c.getString(1));
            namaNilaiList.add(namaNilai[i]);
            i++;
            c.moveToNext();
        }' why you don’t just input your data into the list? Like  'namaNilaiList.add(new NamaNilai(c.getString(0), c.getString(1)););'